# Spring Mongo Agregation Query

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot

I'm new to using Mongo DB in Spring. I have a mongo db query

```
[
    { "$group": {
        "_id": {
            "email": "$email",
            "faxType": "$faxType"
        },
        "faxCount": { "$sum": 1 }
    }},
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id.email",
        "faxTypes": { 
            "$push": { 
                "faxType": "$_id.faxType",
                "count": "$faxCount"
            },
        },
        "count": { "$sum": "$faxCount" }
    }},
    { "$sort": { "count": -1 } },
    { "$limit": 2 },
    { "$project": {
        "faxTypes": { "$slice": [ "$faxTypes", 2 ] },
        "count": 1
    }}
]
```

I need the equivalent of above that i can execute in SpringBoot using Mongo Template. I tried converting above using MongoCompass, but the resultant query gives compile time error.

I understand that i need to create multiple Groups.. So i started with first like this

```
GroupOperation groupOperationOne = Aggregation.group(propertyName, "faxType").count().as("faxCount");

GroupOperation groupOperationTwo = Aggregation.group(groupOperationOne.getFields().getField("email")).push("faxTypes");
```

I'm unable to figure out how to refer to _id.email from first Group Operation.

Each document in collection has an email, and a faxType (Inbound or Outbound). I need to group all records based on email and for each email, i need count of INBOUND faxType and OUTBOUND